# How do I provide a file to edit an XML file on another person's computer?

Tags: xml, edit

Is there a way, possibly in visual basic, to provide a file to a user so that it edits an XML for them, other than me walking them through the process?

I want to provide a preset to them for an application they have, but in order for it to work, that XML file I mentioned needs to be edited.

Is there an automated way to do this? I'd consider providing a .bat file, but I'm concerned they may think, or be concerned, that it's a virus.

Open to any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, provide them with an XSLT stylesheet that performs the necessary transformation.